# Is there a special name for a queue that works with groups of elements

Tags: data-structures, queues

I have a data type that accepts and returns byte arrays. However, the input is from a network callback or loading a huge file in piecemeal and the output is CRLF-terminated lines. The internal storage isn’t groups of bytes, but a single packet of bytes where the partitions extracted don’t have to match the ones inserted. Is there a existing special name for this? Otherwise I’ll call it something like “parsing queue.”